# in (x)ubuntu 16 screen goes in sleep-mode and blocks computer

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, 16.04

While installing, after a while the screen goes in sleep-mode (=normal), but awake is not possible anymore.
The screen is black and the keyboard is blocked (even numlock)
Same thing occurs in a running ubuntu 16 and also xubuntu 16.
Only a forced hardware shutdown and restart is possible.

Tested on an older computer with 64bit and 2 GB.

Is there a solution?